# Update JSON state object problems

Tags: reactjs

I am having difficulty updating my JSON state object.  The basic premise behind my application is that I have a parent component with a child components embedded.  Based on certain user interactions a child component will load in edit mode allowing the user to change fields in the form (otherwise its read-only).

Based on changes in the child component form the changes are successfully being passed back to the Parent to the function (onOverviewChange).  The fieldName and fieldValue seem to be getting passed back correctly, however I can't seem to update state with the new values.

Any thoughts on how to solve this issue?

Parent Component

```
export default class Patient extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   autoBind(this);
   ...
   this.onOverviewChange = this.onOverviewChange.bind(this);
 }

onOverviewChange(event) {
    const fieldName = event.target.name;
    const fieldValue = event.target.value;
    const fieldID = event.target.id;
    /* Approach # 1: This way updates states but doesn't allow me to change the text box*/
         this.setState((prevState) => {
            let patient = [...prevState.PATIENT];
            patient[0] = {...patient[0], [fieldName]: fieldValue};
            console.log("JSON:" + JSON.stringify(patient[0]));
            return({patient});
          });

    /* Approach # 2:  this way updates the text box but not the state
    let patient = [...this.state.PATIENT];
    console.log("Target Name:" + fieldName +". Value:" + fieldValue + " ID: " + fieldID + ". JSON:" + JSON.stringify(patient));
    patient[0] = {...patient[0], [fieldName]: fieldValue};
    this.setState({PATIENT: patient}); */
  }

render() {
...
  <OverviewWrapper onchange={this.onOverviewChange} overview={this.state.PATIENT} ovtype={this.state.COMPPROPS} />
...
}
```

Overview Wrapper component determines if the panel will appear as read-only or editable...

```
 export default class OverviewWrapper extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    autoBind(this);
  }

render() {

    const overview = this.props.overview;
    const type = this.props.compState;

    let OverviewWrapper = null
    switch (type) {
        case "Edit" : 
            OverviewWrapper = OverviewEditPane
            break
        default: 
            OverviewWrapper = OverviewPane
            break
    }

    return <OverviewWrapper {...this.props}  />
}
}
```

Then I have my editable child component where users can change values

```
export default class OverviewEditPane extends React.Component {  

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  autoBind(this);

}

render () {
  return (
          <table>
            <FormFields>
                <tr>
                  <td>{this.props.overview.map((P) => {return <TextInput size='small'  key={P.id} id={P.id} value={P.FName} onChange={P.onOverviewChange}  />;})}</td>
                  **<!--OTHER FIELDS LISTED HERE --->**
                </tr>
```

Patient Data JSON

```
"PATIENT": [{
    "id": 6,
    "FName": "Chris",
    "LName": "Baker",
    "Height": "62",
    "Weight": 320,
    "DOB": "1988-09-18T00:00:00",
    "Active": true
  }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that **React state changes are not synchronous**; when you are modifying the state by relying on the old state value you must switch to the functional `setState` signature. See https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

So:

```
onOverviewChange(event) {
    const fieldName = event.target.name;
    const fieldValue = event.target.value;
    const fieldID = event.target.id;
    this.setState((oldState) => {
        let patient = [...oldState.PATIENT];
        console.log("Target Name:" + fieldName +". Value:" + fieldValue + " ID: " + fieldID + ". JSON:" + JSON.stringify(patient));
        patient[0] = {...patient[0], [fieldName]: fieldValue};
        return({ patient });
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry for the delay i have updated my code with something similar to  your code above.  It does allow me to store an updated state however my text box doesn't appear to allow me to remove characters.  The second approach that is commented out in Overview allows me to apply edits to the form but doesn't allow me to save the updated state.

Answer (score 0):

> JavaScript is a case-sensitive language. This means that language
>   keywords, variables, function names, and any other identifiers must
>   always be typed with a consistent capitalization of letters

You need to keep the consistency of your state properties name, when you do this :

```
this.setState({patient});
```

Your state becomes :

```
{
  PATIENT: [{"id": 6, ......}],
  patient: [{"id": 6, ......, updatedField: value}]
}
```

I suggest you to initialize your state with the non-capitalized name ("patient") and use only this one.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    patient: PATIENT
  }
}
```